# Trouble getting count of negative number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several inputs in the same class and a function that returns false if any of these inputs are empty. What I am trying to do is return false if any of the inputs are negative numbers. I think there might be a way to do this using a regex but am unsure how to go about it.

This is what I have so far.

```
          var $nonneg = $('.quantity').filter(function(){
            return this.value < 0;
          });
          if ($nonneg.length != 0) {
            return false;
          }
```

Comment: If you are able to get the `.quantity` elements into an array, you can use the `Array.every` method to check they all pass a condition, in this case if they are all positive `true` or if any are negative `false`.

Comment: If you want check if something is only a positive number you could try isNaN(this.value) || this.value < 0;

Comment: Your title and question conflict. Are you trying to count the number of inputs with negative values, or simply return false the first time you encounter one?

Comment: `return this.value =''` is wrong... so you need to add acheck where you turn the string to a number and see if it is less than 0

Comment: I am trying to return false if any input is negative. I would like to do something like return this.value = (regex for negative number)

Comment: Why a reg exp when you can just check the number? :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably it should be  return `this.value =='';`

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to check if the value for 3 conditions:

1. equal `===` to empty string `""`
2. If coercing the value to a `Number` results in `NaN`
3. If the number (when coerced) is less than zero.

You can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=example) to check your conditions and return the value. Here's an example of how it can work:

```js
$(".check-inputs").on("click", function () {
  console.log(anyInvalid());
});

function anyInvalid () {
  return Array.prototype.some.bind($(".quantity"))(function (elem) {
    return elem.value === "" || isNaN(Number(elem.value)) || Number(elem.value) < 0;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="quantity" value="1"/><br/>
<input type="text" class="quantity" value="2"/><br/>
<input type="text" class="quantity" value="3"/><br/>
<input type="text" class="quantity" value="-4"/><br/>
<input type="text" class="quantity" value=""/><br/>

<button class="check-inputs">Check Inputs</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?v=control) function to check that every input in the array passes a given test. First, get the inputs as an array using jQuery's [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/). Then run the elements through Array.prototype.every and it will return false if any elements fail the given test.

```js
function arePositiveOrZero(selector){
  return $(selector)
           .get() // Convert to array
           .every( node => parseInt(node.value) >= 0 ) // Check all elements are >= 0
}

// Tests that log to the console
console.log({hasNeg: arePositiveOrZero('.hasNeg')}) // false
console.log({hasBlank: arePositiveOrZero('.hasBlank')}) // false
console.log({hasZero: arePositiveOrZero('.hasZero')}) // true
console.log({allPos: arePositiveOrZero('.allPos')}) // true
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="hasNeg" type="text" value="1">
<input class="hasNeg" type="text" value="-1">

<input class="hasZero" type="text" value="0">
<input class="hasZero" type="text" value="1">

<input class="hasBlank" type="text" value="1">
<input class="hasBlank" type="text" value="">

<input class="allPos" type="text" value="2">
<input class="allPos" type="text" value="3">
```

If you don't want to include zero, just change the test function to `node => node.value > 0`

Comment: `node.value` is a string

Comment: And? You can still do comparisons on it.

Comment: It seems a little odd, but it's just doing a stringwise comparison and "-" < 0

Comment: @mhodges, it looks like I can shave some code with parseInt. Thanks for badgering me!

Comment: parseInt does not guarantee a number. It parses a string for numbers until it reaches a non-number. `parseInt("21GunSalute")` returns `21`, whereas `Number("21GunSalute")` returns `NaN`

Comment: The "stringwise comparison" you referred to coerces to `Number` internally, not `parseInt` for that very reason.

Comment: Yeah, NaN >= 0 === false, so that's a desired behavior

Comment: Right, that's my point - parseInt does not return `NaN` if the value starts with numbers but also contains letters.

Comment: i.e. `parseInt("21GunSalute") > 0 // === true`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me, it returns false if it finds a number less than zero. I was making it out to be more complex than it should have been.

```
          var $nonneg = $('.quantity').filter(function(){
            return this.value < 0;
          });
          if ($nonneg.length != 0) {
            return false;
          }
```